# powershell get-childitem assign lastest directory name to variable

Tags: powershell, scripting

Using powershell  get-childitem  to read the last written directory name  out of the c:\users directory to get the last user that logged onto a machine.

Need only the name of the directory without the @{Name=  .  Is there a way to assign the  name only to the variable?

```
 $uid =  get-childitem  \\e934-hvy-xx\c$\users | sort LastWriteTime  -Descending |  select  -First 1   name 


$WSuser =  "\\e934-hvy-xx\c$\workAHTD\" + $uid

[System.Console]::WriteLine($uid); 
[System.Console]::WriteLine($WSuser );
```

returns:

```
@{Name=csle999}

\\e934-hvy-xx\c$\workAHTD\@{Name=csle999}
```

Searched the web for an answer - if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: `Select-Object -Expand`

Comment: Ansgar I tried it and it gave me a error. Must not have placed in correctly in the line. Researching that command to see how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$WSuser =  "\\e934-hvy-xx\c$\workAHTD\" + $uid.Name
```

This will return Bob007 from @{Name=Bob007}

Comment: Thank you for the help  - this is my first powershell and as always there is LOTS to learn.   Worked great and marked as answer!

Comment: `$uid | fl` will show you whats available within the variable. In this case, just Name. So we get to `$uid.Name`